# Can't get this html5 audio to play on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mobile

I have this audio source

```
 <aside class="audio">
     <audio id="the-fight-audio">
         <source src="audio/the-fight.ogg">
         <source src="audio/the-fight.mp3">
    </audio>
</aside>
```

And I use this javascript to play it

```
// Play button action
    $('.song .play').click(function(){
        var song = $(this).data('song'),
        audio = $('audio#'+song+'-audio');
        $('audio').each(function(){
            this.pause(); // Stop playing
            this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
        }); 

        audio[0].play();
    });
```

It works on desktop but not on the phone, is there something I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: What mobile browser are you using? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats Scroll all the way down for compatable media types by different browsers

Comment: w3schools recommends also using the <embed> element, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp . In addition, are you specifying any media rules in your css for mobile devices ? i.e. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: I'm using mobile chrome and also tried safari, both on ios7. I have also added the embed code in the audio element and it still doesn't play the audio.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the pausing bit before the play part, if I remove that the audio plays, but if it's there it doesn't play at all